# get x y on click from pdf

Tags: php, pdf

i want to open a pdf file in my web application , let users click in some area
 and get the x y coordinate
 affiche a textbox and submit it to php script

if you can tell me how to display pdf in a iframe , and get xy from it ?

Comment: what have you tried until now? where exact is the problem? what should we do for you? write the complete code?

Comment: now i can open pdf file and write in , and save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is "not possible", except you render the pdf as image with i.e. the imagemagick "convert" tool display the generated image. Then you could use javascript or the picture as an image submit button where you get the coordinates.

Comment: thank you , it seems to be nice way , but what about resources ? i will do this a lot of times , create labels update and remove , i will try and give you feedback